# Spark file stream syntax

Tags: apache-spark

```
        JavaPairInputDStream<Text, BytesWritable> dStream = jsc.fileStream("/home/suv/junk/sparkInput");
```

when am running this code i am getting

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat
```

I am unable to mention the input format in the file stream. How to give this input format.
This is the method signature i got

```
public <K,V,F extends org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.InputFormat<K,V>> JavaPairInputDStream<K,V> fileStream(String directory).
```

In this how to specify the input format.

Answer (score 0):

After wasting all my day...wrote a utility in scala..

```
class ZipFileStream {
  def fileStream(path: String, ssc: StreamingContext): JavaPairInputDStream[Text, BytesWritable] = {
    return ssc.fileStream[Text, BytesWritable, ZipFileInputFormat](path)

  }
}
```

and refereed this from java.
Any better solution appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue.

It seems to be a bug, which was fixed Spark 1.3.0

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5297